# Tailwind CSS, Next.js Image Component Mosaic Like Design

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

How do you get the images to show up like this?

[image]

Some of the images are seen to be cut off, or at least it looks that way, or if the size fits, it'll find an image inside the categories to fit in here (I think this would be more complicated to find the images of the right sizing)

I know that NextJS has Image component, but it requires a width/height or `layout='fill'`. So would there be an easy css way of doing something similar to the images?

Comment: Search "masonry grid" "image gallery" on some search engine or CodePen, you will get the necessary CSS code to begin with. You may even get some react libraries which can then be directly used in Next.js. Also you don't need to find images of right sizing. Just find ones with not so extreme aspect ratio, they are basically fixed width (`max-width: 33%; height: auto`) in the example you have shown. Flexbox with [gutters](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap) should do the trick for basic layout in TailwindCSS.

Comment: you could set a fixed width and set height auto.